# Swift: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION called when calling function

Tags: arrays, swift

So I'm trying to get a standard deviation function to work, however I'm running into an error.  Here's my code:

```
func standardDeviation(dataSet: [Double]) -> Double {
let mean = dataSet.reduce(0, +) / Double(dataSet.count)
var distances = [Double]()
for number in dataSet {
    let distanceFromMean = (dataSet[Int(number)] - mean)
    distances.append(distanceFromMean * distanceFromMean)
}

return distances.reduce(0, +) / Double(dataSet.count)
}
```

It outputs the following error:

> Fatal Error: Index out of range

So, I had a feeling that it was something to do when I call the dataSet array, so when I looked into that, I found this as an error

> error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0).
>   The process has been left at the point where it was interrupted, use "thread return -x" to return to the state before expression evaluation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`number` (a `Double`!) cannot be an index to subscribe `dataSet`, so I'm quite sure you *mean*

```
let distanceFromMean = number - mean
```

as in the `Fast Enumeration` pattern the index variable `number` is actually equal to `array[index]`